# Expo-camera unable to mirror front camera video

Tags: android, react-native, ffmpeg, camera, expo

I am using FFMPEG and expo-camera in an expo managed app.
I am trying to concat videos from front and back cameras.

However, because front camera is not able to mirror my front camera videos, the videos do not have same orientation and I am not able to concat videos taken with both cameras.

In my settings I have allowed mirroring front-camera media.
Does anyone know how to allow mirroring on expo-camera ?